# Safari page loading scrolls to near bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

On Safari 13, when I load a wordpress page, it scrolls to an Google Map Iframe near the bottom of the page. I tried fixing it with JS:

```
$(document).ready( () => {

    window.scrollTo(0,0);

})
```

to no effect. This doesn't happen on Chrome Mac or PC. Any suggestions about how to fix this or work around? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok we figured it out. Apparently, the Google map at the bottom of the page has a marker for a location. When the marker loads, Safari focuses on that marker causing the page to skip to the map. This does not occur with Chrome. We ended up only running the JavaScript function creating the marker for non-Safari browsers using a regular expression to select for non-Safari browsers and this fixed the page jump.